Phantom Wallet Incorrectly Flagging Website as Scam
I would like you to review the URL stake.tars.pro as it has been flagged as a scam by Phantom wallet. I am part of the TARS team and I was able to stake with no issues - have contacted blowfish, scamsniffer and metamask but there doesn't seem to be an easy fix for this. How could we get the warnings removed on the tx screen?
https://solscan.io/tx/3hJ7f11KmNeMtPN9KjMDwEc7pVDkdgucfn3QjMNPmtM4227RJJFAoyn9Huv9S7MANdW3144ZiniJKVGbpZkCzHx
https://solscan.io/tx/2dDUvjuJKYFy9wpsbNmwami467xvsvDMTNdV9QzQsM9urkJE5k4TFzuATrVxQxoSKNfzqZ18fjfLwGQCHMUEtCyV
ty

You need to email review@blowfish.xyz and give all the information they request in the automatic Zendesk reply and follow up to ensure they add to their approve list

Problem is they no longer reply, and Phantom isn't very active on their blocklist repo.

@ThickMiddleManager did you manage to resolve this with blowfish ? I’m in same position

Blowfish is not fast, but they do get the job done. Let me know if it's urgent and the reason why. Also feel free to drop the URL
